# Parse PHP SDK connects successfullly to parse server on wamp but not on ipage

Tags: php, parse-platform, wamp

I developed php code on WAMP (PHP version 5.5) using the parse php sdk version 1.2 to connect to my parse-server. Everything works perfectly on WAMP. I made the necessary changes concerning file directories and uploaded the script to ipage (PHP version 5.5). Now whenever I try this same code I get ParseExecption "Couldn't connect to host".

```
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
use Parse\ParseClient;



$app_id='XXXXXXXXX';
$master_key='XXXXXXXXX';
$rest_key='XXXXXXXX';

Parse\ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
// Users of Parse Server will need to point ParseClient at their remote URL:
Parse\ParseClient::setServerURL('http://XXXXXXXXXX:XXXX/parse');
```

This code works perfectly on my WAMP server but not on ipage. What I don't understand is when I change the server addrress to "https://api.parse.com/1" and make to necessary client key changes the works with Parse.com. The code works with my parse-server on WAMP but not on ipage.

Comment: Just in case you didnt know http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/